# Using user input (io.read) as function argument in Lua

Tags: lua

> ***made in portuguese sorry***

ok so basically i have this function:

```
function perfil(monstro)
 print(monstros.monstro.nomeM)
 print(monstros.monstro.racaM)
 print(monstros.monstro.generoM)
 print(monstros.monstro.idadeM)
 print(monstros.monstro.descM)
end
```

and this table:

```
monstros = {
  Esqueleto = {nomeM = "Skeletran", racaM = "Esqueleto", generoM = "F", idadeM = "455", descM = "'Estou morta mas não o suficiente!'"},
  Zumbi = {nomeM = "Bruce Santos", racaM = "Zumbi", generoM = "M", idadeM = "19", descM = "'Prociza ter umh celbro de 17 centismotros       .'"},
  Sirena = {nomeM = "Alamellia", racaM = "Sirena", generoM = "F", idadeM = "18", descM = "'Minhas canções são as melhores! Inspirante á Cantora :-D'"},
  Ogro = {nomeM = "Crak", racaM = "Ogro", generoM = "M", idadeM = "34", descM = "'hngbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbyæ'"},
  Dragoa = {nomeM = "SUZANA", racaM = "DRAGÂO", generoM = "F", idadeM = "1367", descM = "'GOOSTO DE FLORESS VERMELHHAS'"}
  }
```

and i want to make it so that `io.read` input changes the parameter `monstro` on the function `perfil`.
sorry if the solution is something easy, i'm pretty new to programming and Lua.
Also, if theres a error or bad thing in my code, tell me ! (i know i need to use [this](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) for accent marks)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function perfil(monstro)
 monstro = monstros[monstro] --take the input and find the matching key in the table
 print(monstro.nomeM)        --print the corresponding 'nomeM' for that key
 print(monstro.racaM)
 --... and so on
end

perfil(io.read())   --call the function io.read() and take the input as parameter
```

I don't know what you actually intend to do with these keys but depending on what you need, you could iterate over them like this:

```
function perfil(monstro)
 print(monstro)
 for key, value in pairs(monstros[monstro]) do
  print("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
 end
end

perfil('Ogro')
```

Output:

```
Ogro
Key:    idadeM  Value:  34
Key:    generoM Value:  M
Key:    racaM   Value:  Ogro
Key:    descM   Value:  'hngbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbyæ'
Key:    nomeM   Value:  Crak
```